# Measuring css properties as applied by jQuery animation

Tags: jquery, dom

Let's say there's a div that has a fadeToggle method going on:

```
$('.someDiv').fadeToggle(500);
```

This has an opacity animation that lasts 500ms, preceded and followed by a 'display' css property change (from 'none' to 'block' and viceversa). It adds these properties in the DOM, if I'm not mistaken.

Could I measure or check those properties as they happen, like so?

```
if ($('.someDiv').css("opacity") != "1"){
   //Do Something
}
```

I tried and it seems to have no effect.

Comment: You mean you want to check whether the block is fading in or fading out?

Comment: No, sorry if I wasn't clear enough. Here's what I mean: while the div is fading in or out, it changes opacity. In the moments when opacity is not 1 (because it's fading in or out), could I "do" something?

Comment: Why not? It is definitely possible. How is your code not working? What do you want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `setInterval` before calling the `fadeToggle`, and then use a callback to clear it.

```
$('.someDiv').click(function() {
    var interval = setInterval(opacityTrace,1);
    $('.someDiv').fadeToggle(500,function() { clearInterval(interval) });
});

function opacityTrace() {
    var currentOpacity = $('.someDiv').css("opacity");
    $(".opacityTrace").append(currentOpacity+"<br/>");
}
```

Example fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/jdcejscn/1/

Comment: Whoa, this is exactly what I was looking for. You rock.